# Convert Return String from PHP into JSON Object

Tags: php, objective-c, json

I have an HTTP Post request that returns a JSON object. I can view the return value as a string and it is perfect. What I am stuck on is converting this return value into something that can be parsed as a JSON object. I'm not sure of the conceptual steps, much less the code that I should be writing.

Here is the code that I have. It crashes the JSON serialization line because the line before it where I attempt to convert the return string into NSData results in a nil value. Not even sure if I need this step, but I can't find a successful solution.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

```
- (void) finished: (NSNotification *) n
{
    MyDownloader *d = [n object];
    NSData *data = nil;
    if ([n userInfo]) {
        NSLog(@"information retrieval failed");
    } else {
        data = d.receivedData;
        NSString *text=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:d.receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@", text);

        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:text];
        self.response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

        if (self.response)
            [self parseJSONObject];
        else NSLog(@"The server has responded with something other than a JSON formatted object");
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name: @"connectionFinished"
                                                  object:d];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `dataWithContentsOfFile`, which is trying to load the data from a file in your local filesystem. Use this instead:

```
NSData *data = [text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

However, as @MartinR points out, there's no need to convert `d.recievedData` to a string and then back to data. Just use it directly.

```
NSData *data = d.recievedData;
```

Comment: Even that is not necessary, because `d.receivedData` already contains the JSON data. No need to convert it to a string and back.

Comment: @Jake King -  your solution worked. @Martin R - can you please suggest a line of code where I can directly use `d.receivedData`? This is the part that I am hung up on - how to get from my received data into something that I can parse. Thanks to you both!

Comment: `self.response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:d.receivedData ...`